# fullbody detection and estimating height of human by using emgucv

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I am developing program for estimating height of human by using emgucv. I use fullbodydetection to detect human body. I use height of detected rectangular box as reference to estimating height.

My program is written as below. I used vb as my programing language

```
    imgcolor = ImgCap.QueryFrame.Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FLIP.HORIZONTAL)
    imggray = imgcolor.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()

    If TextBox1.Text = "Human Detected" Then
        TextBox2.Text = Height
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = 0


    End If

    TextBox1.Text = "Human Detected"


    For Each body As MCvAvgComp In imggray.DetectHaarCascade( _
    objecttodetect, _
    1.2, _
    1, _
         CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, _
    New Size(50, 50))(0) 
        imgcolor.Draw(body.rect, New Bgr(Color.Blue), 3)


        Height = body.rect.Height
```

My questions are

1) When i debugged full body detection was not accurate. What should i do to make the detection result accurate?

2) the current size of my image box was 640,480. I wanted to reduce width to 320 but when i do that the view in the image box was halfed as well as my camer (means even if i cover the half of my camera lens it doesn''t affect to image in image box.

Thx in advance for your answer. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer for question 1, but I can answer question 2:

You need to look at the `SetZoomScale` method of `ImageBox`. I wrote this method to automatically scale the ImageBox if the image is too large. It's in C# but you should probably be able to convert it to VB.

```
private void ScaleImageBox(Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox imgBox, Size imgSize)
{
    float scaleFactor = 1;
    if (imgSize.Width > imgBox.Width || imgSize.Height > imgBox.Height)
    {
        float widthFactor = imgBox.Width / (float)imgSize.Width;
        float heightFactor = imgBox.Height / (float)imgSize.Height;
        scaleFactor = Math.Min(widthFactor, heightFactor);
    }
    imgBox.SetZoomScale(scaleFactor, new Point(0, 0));
}
```